# SQL 2008 Express database user name and password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have published my ASP.Net MVC 2 application. I have a login service which works localy but when I try to do the same things online I have a problem. I had to edit the web.config file to point to the database on the web server. Also i hade to provide a username and password to access this database but i haven't set any. The connection string looks like this:

`<add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Server=servername;Database=database;Uid=uid;Password=pwd"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I can not leave the uid and password empty because i am getting an error. I think i have to add a username and password to my database but I dont know how to do it. I have googled a lot but found nothing. Hope someone can help

Comment: The error is that it can not log in for user ""...if I dont enter Uid and Password in the web.config file then i get the error that it cant log in for user "DENVER\"...

Answer (score 0):

This site is a good resource for connection string info:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

You probably want to use a trusted connection until you create some users in your DB.

Something like this:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" 
     connectionString="Server=servername;Database=database;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When/if you start to add users to the database take a look at this link:

http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/adding-users-in-sql-server.html